# Render component passed as props

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I am working on a component which renders "buttons" - an icon which trigger some function on click. 
 I'm passing the data as props, but the icons are actually components since I am using mdue library and I have problem rendering them properly.

My buttons array which I pass as props and icons import:

```js
import {
  FormatBold, FormatItalic,
} from 'mdue';

buttons: [
  { icon: FormatBold, onClick: someFunction() },
  { icon: FormatItalic, onClick: someFunction() },
]
```

And here's how I am trying to display them in my other component

```
<div v-for="(button, index) in buttons" :key="index" @click="someFunction">
  {{ button.icon }}
</div>
```

What is displayed on the screen: 
{ "name": "" }
{ "name": "" }

The proper way of using icons from that library:

```
<template>
  <format-bold></format-bold>
</template>
```

Comment: additionally, `onClick: someFunction()` and `@click="someFunction"` is wrong, most likly it should be `onClick: someFunction` and  `@click="button.onClick"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your icons are components rather than just the names of the icons - you should render them using the `component` tag and not interpolating their contents:

```html
<button v-for="(button, index) in buttons" :key="index" @click="button.onClick">
  <template v-if="button.icon">
    <component :is="button.icon" />
  </template>
</button>
```